# Node.js - Regex test always false on file

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a log file where each line has this information:

```
[Thu Mar 30 2017 11:24:51 GMT+0100 (WEST)] {"serial":"CA-2M-1107619","type":"iface","body":{"action":"up","device":"tun_man","ip":"127.255.0.10","ip6":"2016:900d:c0de::1001"}
```

I want to parse the line and get the timestamp `Thu Mar 30 2017 11:24:51 GMT+0100 (WEST)` and the data between `{}`.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
var lineReader = require('line-reader');
var Regex = require('regex');
var regexTimestamp = new Regex("/\w+\s\w+\s\d+\s\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+\s\w+\+\d+\s\(\w+\)/");
var regexData = new Regex("/{.+}/");

var path = '/var/log/wscontroller_logevents1.log';
lineReader.open(path, function(err, reader) {
  if (err) throw err;
  if (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    reader.nextLine(function(err, line) {
      try {
        if (err) throw err;
        var testLine = '[Fri Apr 21 2017 13:09:51 GMT+0100 (WEST)] {"serial":"CA-2M-1128568","type":"iface","body":{"action":"ifupdate","device":"wan","ip":"","ip6":""}}';
        var testDate = '[Fri Apr 21 2017 13:44:53 GMT+0100 (WEST)]';
        var testData = '{"serial":"CA-2M-1128568","type":"iface","body":{"action":"ifupdate","device":"wan","ip":"","ip6":""}}';
        console.log('-----');
        console.log('-----');
        console.log('line', line);
        console.log('-----');
        console.log('-----');
        console.log('Date: ',regexTimestamp.test(testDate));
        console.log('Data: ',regexData.test(testData));
      } finally {
        reader.close(function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
        });
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    reader.close(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the reverse approach: look for the content between brackets.

```
var regexTimestamp = /\[(.*)\]/;

// ...

console.log('Date: ',regexTimestamp.test(testDate));
// [
//   "[Fri Apr 21 2017 13:44:53 GMT+0100 (WEST)]", 
//   "Fri Apr 21 2017 13:44:53 GMT+0100 (WEST)"
// ]
```